# lateral cell space tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with various cells and I want to insert lateral space (to the right and to the left) between the cell and the `View`, but I am not able to do that.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: So you want a table view with a width that is less than the width of your viewport?

Comment: are you using a Table View Controller, or a Normal View Controller with a table View Object? If its the last option, you should just use auto layout with separation of edges, if not, you should change to a Normal View Controller with a Table View Object.

Comment: I use view controller with a tableview inside

Comment: sorry @MagoNicolasPalacios but I dont understand how do I do?

Comment: Ok, if you are using view controller with table View inside, you should just use auto layout with the margins you want (The space right and left you want)

Comment: can you explain better to achive it? I'm new in this world...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to make the TableView's width shorter that the controller's view width and add constraints to keep the space exactly as you want it.
[image]

Another way is to design your cell with an "internal container" with spacings to edge of the cell's content view.[image]

Comment: easist way to do it. Wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a UICollectionView instead.

With UICollectionView, you can set the Cell's Width and Height, and add custom spacing between each cells. You can also configure the space between the cell and the border of the CollectionView.

---

If you really need a UITableView, try to add a **Leading Space To Container Margin** and a **Trailing Space To Container Margin** contraint between your UITableView and its Superview.

Here is an example : my tableview has a grey background, my cell has a yellow background and the superview has a blue background. Thank to the two constraints, there is a space on the left and the right of my cell

[image]

Is that what you need ?

Comment: I have to use uitableview

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this in a storyboard using a **container view**…
[image]
Add a **container view** to your view controller, set the left and right constraints to the inset you need, add a `UITableViewController` and then drag from the container to the table view controller and *embed* it